# Conditional .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sure there are other threads on similar topics around the web but I just can't get this working on my own website.

The problem is that I have a multi-language website where the selected language is controlled through the URL. Right now the url is:

```
www.website.com/en/order
```

or whatever for English or

```
www.website.com/da/order
```

for Danish. This is all working just fine however I want to be able to use just the plain URL for the default language, for instance `www.website.com/order` where it'll then just select the default language (which I have defined in my php code).

Is there any easy way to do this using .htaccess? Right now my .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [nc]
```

I've also tried having two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [nc]
```

But nothing works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should catch all URLs that do not start with a 2-letter language code, and simply rewrite all those that do, to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# match those that DO have a language code
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Of course, you want to make sure you don't have any page URLs that are also 2-letter combinations...

If you only have a small set of languages to support (e.g. "da", "en", "de"), you could make it more robust by using this instead

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(da|en|de)/ [NC]
```

By the way, you'll want to always remember to use the QSA-flag to append any existing GET paramters to the rewritten URL.

Comment: @simon: Strange, seems to work ok here. Is it you webserver or php that's giving the error? -- ignore that, I'm getting an error too now :-P

Comment: 500 internal server error - must be the server as there's really no way my php code could generate that error right now..

Comment: @Simon: Just made some corrections - it should work now. I messed up the flag syntax when I posted.

Comment: @Simon: No prob (or, since I'm guessing you're Danish: Det var så lidt)

Comment: Det er jeg, men det er altid godt at tage den på engelsk så andre kan være med herinde ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond). For (an untested and probably wrong) example, using English as the default:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/..\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/(..)\/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/(.*) index.php?lang=en&page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: This is a problem though because the "order" was just an example. I will have a whole lot of different pages I would want to apply this to. I have tried the following with no luck:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.*) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [nc]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/..\/(.*) [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [nc]`

Comment: If all the country codes are two chars, then you can try my example again. I changed it slightly.

Comment: Well the part where the language code exist works now but without the language code I just get "404 not found".. Well if I just go to the main domain `www.website.com ` everything looks just fine but as soon as I click a link (`www.website.com/contact`) it gives me 404. No problem with `www.website.com/en/contact`

Comment: Check your access logs and see what page it tried to fetch. It should have been index.php?lang=en&page=$1.